# PHP if is a multiple of an integer

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop

Within a for loop, i need to add some HTML that outputs only when the loop is on a [(multiple of 3) minus 1].

For example, what i could do is:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($imagearray); $i++)
{
    if($i=="0" || $i=="2" || $i=="5" || $i=="8" || $i=="11")
    {
        echo 'string';
    }
}
```

but this isnt very elegant and extremely useless for big for loops, is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: why do you compare with strings? 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ( $i==0 || ($i+1)%3 == 0 )
{
    //do stuff
}
```

What this will do, is go to the next index, divide it by 3, and see if there is a remainder. If there is none, then that means that the current index is one less than a number that is divisible by 3

Comment: 0 doesn't meet the condition of number that is divisible by 3 minus one. But if it needs to be added, thats a simple `if ($i == 0 ||...`

Comment: I just added $i==0 for the 0 addition, thanks for the answer Joe. Will accept answer when i can, cant yet

Comment: @JoeCortopassi I know,that `0` doesn't meet your modulos condition.But from the question, it is obvious, that your condition should include that case also.

Answer (score 0):

Use [the modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

```
if (! (($i+1) % 3) ) {
```

If `$i+1` divides into 3 with no remainder, the result will be zero. Then you just need a boolean *not*.

If you want to match 0 as well (since you use it in your example, but it doesn't match your description) then you will have to special case it with an `||`.

Comment: Why would you choose this over a comparison operator? I sincerely doubt it would be any faster and it's sure a whole lot more confusing to use not-logic over normal logic.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the modulo for that:

```
(1 % 3) == 1
(2 % 3) == 2
(3 % 3) == 0
(4 % 3) == 1
```

Good luck

Modulo is the same thing as saying, give me the remainder of a division. So 1 / 3 equals 0 remainder 1, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(($i+1)%3 == 0){
    //do something
}
```

The % operator is known as the modulus operator and returns the remainder of a division.

Answer (score 0):

the most elegent method is thus

```
if ($i % 3 === 2) {
  //do stuff
}
```

as it doesn't add things to the `$i` value, but all answers are essentially correct!

Comment: I imagine this is being used to create a layout of images with three columns, if so, remember that if your site is viewed on different screens that the images might appear differently and that you shouldn't be using PHP to make layout decisions because of the multi-screen issue. JavaScript/CSS would be best to arrange your content.